# imperative + will you?

Tags: connotations, imperative-sentences

What effect does the "will you?" tag at the end of a question have? To my ear, it sounds a little rude, adds emphasis. "Be quiet, will you?" As compared with the bare imperative which is sort of dead and lifeless.

Comment: It adds a note of impatience; it could be used when the speaker has already made the request and been ignored.

Comment: In different contexts, adding "will you?" will have different effects. In your example, it makes the statement sound even more rude and curt than "Be quiet" alone. But for something like, "Hand me my glasses, will you?" it makes the request more polite. To my ear, "will you?" after an imperative always sounds like an elderly person speaking, whether rude or polite.